# X509Chain.Build() method returns true for Invalid certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I am attempting to write code to validate an SSL certificate as follows;

```
HttpWebRequest request = 
         HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.someurl.com");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();

    X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

    var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    X509ChainPolicy chainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
    {
                        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
                        RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain
    };
    chain.ChainPolicy = chainPolicy;

    if (!chain.Build(cert2))
    {
                        foreach (X509ChainElement chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
                        {
                            foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(chainStatus.StatusInformation);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The build method returns true, but it should not be. I can confirm that the cert is invalid by using online checks and also using openSSL.

When I interrogate the chain.ChainElements, there are certificates that are not being sent by the server (this is why the cert is not valid). I am assuming that these are being pulled in elsewhere, but removing any signs of them from the certificate store (for both my account and computer account) they still appear.

I need to be able to validate this certificate only against what it received in the response.

Edit to add output from other sources;

```
> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.someurl.com:443
> CONNECTED(00000003) depth=0 OU = GT99831354, OU = See
> www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15, OU = Domain Control Validated -
> RapidSSL(R), CN = www.someurl.com verify error:num=20:unable to get
> local issuer certificate verify return:1 depth=0 OU = GT99831354, OU =
> See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15, OU = Domain Control
> Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = www.someurl.com verify
> error:num=27:certificate not trusted
```

A working certificate;

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = RapidSSL SHA256 CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.someurl.co.uk
```

Comment: What result you are expecting?

Comment: Well, I need it to confirm what everything else is telling me, that the certificate chain is invalid (it has the wrong intermediate certificate on the server). So, I believe it should return false in this case, perhaps I am misunderstanding what the function does.

Comment: If `Build` method returns `True` like in your configuration, then CryptoAPI was able to successfully construct and validate the chain and it doesn't see any issues with your cert.

Comment: I get that, but it must be being influenced by something on my machine as the intermediate cert on the server (my server) is not correct for the cert chain, so it must be able to construct the correct chain some other way. See the openssl output above, same from other sources.

Comment: CryptoAPI performs various source lookup to gather missing certificates. It is really very smart and even can overcome (sometimes) server misconfiguration when using certificates from trusted commercial CAs.

Comment: Typical, need it to be not so smart!

Comment: Still, I don't see what is your issue. CryptoAPI successfully built and validated the chain. It is not its fault at all. The fact that other tools fail -- it's up to these tools.